# Is it a good practice to have an interface which has default implementation for all of its methods?

Tags: java, java-8, interface

Imagine I have an interface like below:

```
public interface DataChecker<T, C> {

    default ProcessResult beforeProcess(T record, CountertHelper countertHelper, C config){
        return new ProcessResult(false, Collections.emptyList());
    }

    default List<String> checkData(T record, CountertHelper countertHelper, C config) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    class ProcessResult {
        private final boolean skip;
        private final List<String> keys;

        public ProcessResult(boolean skip) {
            this.skip = skip;
            this.keys = Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

Some implementer of this interface may only implement `beforProcess` method and some others may only implement `checkData` method and some others may chose to implement both of them.

Is it a good practice to make both of them `default`? Or more generally is it a good practice to have an interface which has `default` implementation for all of its method.

Comment: Why dont you split ur interface into 2 diff interfaces each with one method , based on usage the class can implements any or both.

Comment: In my opinion (since it's opinion, I vote to close it) just because you CAN add default methods in new interfaces, doesn't mean you SHOULD. It 's meant so they could add methods to old interfaces without crashing applications everywhere, because of backwards compatibility, not so you could put it in new interfaces

Comment: I think it is against interface purpose. Interfaces are mostly used when you want to ensure that a couple of functions (interface) exist on an object and adding behaviors and functionalites is in class scope. As @Stultuske mentioned, default methods were added for backward compatibility. The default implementation can be defined in a separate default open class which implements the interface.

Comment: You can always define an interface and then a default implementation (in AWT/Swing parliance, an "adapter"). Or directly define the superclass without defining an interface (which is closer to what you want to do). Default methods were a way to solve the problem of modifying existing interfaces without breaking compatibility, they are not meant to change the usage of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

As name implies, **default** methods in java 8 are **simply default**. If you do not override them, they are the methods which will be invoked by caller classes.

In you case if the Some class only want `beforProcess` and do not want `checkData` and vice versa I suggest you to split ur interface into 2

like

```
public interface DataChecker<T, C> {

     List<String> checkData(T record, CountertHelper countertHelper, C config);
```

and

```
public interface DataProcessor<T, C> {

     ProcessResult beforeProcess(T record, CountertHelper countertHelper, C config);
```

Now the approach is cleaner and the classes override one or both if implemented both hence a cleaner approach.